# display result based on dynamic span value jquery

Tags: jquery

i have span called `<span id="qty"></div>` where its value is dynamically generated. I created this condition to hide the qty if the result is less than  1 but it does not appear to work

```
   var qty = parseInt($('#qty').text());
    if(qty < 1){
       $('#qty').hide();
    }else{
        $('#qty').show();
    }
```

Comment: Also you have extra qty identifier in else statement, remove that also.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It would help me understand the problem better if you can explain how you're calling this method - is this just a script on the page, or is this code inside a method body being called at a specific point?

Comment: qty is called on image hover , a different number is generated  based on the image

Comment: Try putting a console.log() in there and see what the parsed value is or debug it and see if the execution is flowing through there correctly.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Are you setting the `qty` variable inside the event listener? If not, it won't use the current value when the event occurs, it will use the value from when the page was loaded.

Comment: im just setting it in the footer of my page

Answer (score 0):

The if-else statement only fires once. You need to add an event listener to `#qty` since there's no `change` event on `<span>`.

Here's an example:

```js
$('#qty').on('change', function() {
  var qty = parseInt($(this).text())
  if (qty < 1) {
    $(this).hide()
  } else {
    $(this).show()
  }
})

$('#add').on('click', function() {
  $('#qty').text(parseInt($('#qty').text()) + 1).trigger('change')
})

$('#minus').on('click', function() {
  $('#qty').text(parseInt($('#qty').text()) - 1).trigger('change')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="qty">0</span>
<br>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<button id="minus">Minus</button>
```

Comment: @JeVic No. If you want it triggered on hover, you should add another event listener. But it won't trigger on hover once you hide the '#qty'.